# How do I setup a bluehost email account?

Tags: evolution, email

I have an bluehost's account email and recently I have installed Ubuntu 11.10. Now I want to setup my account in Evolution or Thunderbird but I can't it. I don't know if problem is about the settings or client email can't connect with the server IMAP.

Answer (score 2):

You might just either call them, or send a ticket.  But, I did a search for you on their website helpdesk and here is the link that shows all about thunderbird.

[Blue Host](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/thunderbird)

Comment: Thanks, I connected with the chat live of bluehost and that resolve!!